# How to set a Java Object in Google Protobuf Value

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc-java

I am writing a client that consumes a service(I don't own the service) via GRPC. At run time I get n number of variables/Objects and I don't know the type of these variables/Objects in advance. I have to send all these values to the GRPC service. I see we can set Strings/Boolean/Double etc in Google protobuf value. Is there a way I can set a custom object to Value. Here is the sample code

```
Value v = null;
Struct s = null;
Map<String, Value> valueMap = new HashMap<String, Value>();
for (UpdateSession_Object varList : myRequest.getUpdate_session_list()) {
                if (varList.getSession_var_value() instanceof String) {
                    v = Value.newBuilder().setStringValue(varList.getSession_var_value().toString()).build();
                    valueMap.put(varList.getSession_var_name(), v);
                } else if (varList.getSession_var_value() instanceof Double) {
                    v = Value.newBuilder().setNumberValue((Double) varList.getSession_var_value()).build();
                    valueMap.put(varList.getSession_var_name(), v);
                } else if (varList.getSession_var_value() instanceof Object) {
                    **// How do i set the object to Value**
                }

            }
            s = Struct.newBuilder().putAllFields(valueMap).build();
```

Is there a way I can set the Custom object to Value so that I can send all the incoming variables correctly to GRPC call.

Answer (score 1):

`Value` is a JSON-like data structure. It cannot handle arbitrary Java objects.